# Exclude dates with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query with LINQ this one works great for me

```
List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
          var m = ob.Max(x => x.number);
                Num = m;
                dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                                            where o.number == m  
                                            orderby o.number descending
                                            select o).ToList();
```

now what I need is to exclude a month, that is, tell the query not to show me the month of January and February. TallerDate contains the dates of a list that is, in that tallerDate there are several records with dates of January February and March what I did in this query was to bring the lowest month that would be month 1 is what is left in f, but it is not as it has to be, as I said before, what I need is for tallerDate to not show me the month of January and February but to show me March onwards

```
List<Vehiculos> ob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Vehiculos>>(response.Content);
  var f = ob.Min(x => x.workshopDate.Month);
  nvar m = ob.Max(x => x.number);
  Num = m;
  dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                             where o.number == m && o.workshopDate.Month == f
                             orderby o.number descending
                             select o).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to show records of current month so this should do it:

```
// this picks up the current month number
var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                         where o.number == m && o.workshopDate.Month == currentMonth 
                         orderby o.number descending
                         select o).ToList();
```

to be more precise about filtering the records the more better could be:

```
var currentMonthFirstDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

dataGridView5.DataSource = (from o in ob
                         where o.number == m && o.workshopDate >= currentMonthFirstDate 
                         orderby o.number descending
                         select o).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks friend, it was simple but I didn't see how to do it